# How can I find the indexPoint in this list?

Tags: java, arrays, list, search, arraylist

Currently I'm working on this assignment where I need to check if a letter occurs in a word. I've already figured out on how to print the right letter and count. But I'm struggling on how to print the word where the letter in occurs. Would be great if somebody is able to give me some tips. Thanks!

```
public class joejoe {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String sentence = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
        String[] sentenceList = {"the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumped", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"};
        char[] alphabetList = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q',
                'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
        System.out.println("The sentence: \"" + sentence + "\" contains:");

        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < alphabetList.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < sentenceList.length; j++) {
                String word = sentenceList[j];

                for (int k = 0; k < word.length(); k++) {
                    if (alphabetList[i] == sentence.charAt(j)) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Letter: " + alphabetList[i]);
                System.out.println("Words: " + word);
                System.out.println("Count = " + count);
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My output:

```
Letter: a
Words: the
Count = 0
Letter: a
Words: quick
Count = 0
Letter: a
Words: brown
Count = 0
Letter: a
Words: fox
Count = 0
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess would be easier to iterate over sentenceList and then over the letter of each word so you can keep track of word indexes.

```
for (int i = 0; i < alphabetList.length; i++) {
    
    ...

    for (int j = 0; j < sentenceList.length; j++) {
        String word = sentenceList[j];

        ...

        for (int k = 0; k < word.length(); k++) {
           
            ...

        }
    }
    
    ...

}
```

Comment: Can you have a look at my new code? I still have the wrong output.

Comment: I cannot solve your homework...Now you have the index (j) to retrieve the words from the sentence list. You have to add the logic to store the word in which the letter appears and then print them

Comment: I wasn't trying to get any answers, just trying to get some tips. Thanks for this one, I'll look into it.

Comment: also you should keep the print statements outside the sentenceList loop. You just want to execute that one time for each letter.

Comment: Can you provide me another hint? I've tried this time to move the print statements and I've changed the if-statement, but it doesn't work out. I will try it one more time and otherwise I'll have a look at it tomorrow with a fresh mindset.

Comment: I would keep an array of strings for each letter to store the words in which that letter appears.

Comment: if (alphabetList[i] == sentence.charAt(j)) {
                        count++;
                    }

Just to be sure, is this the right if statement? I don't know where my mistake is so I'm trying to understand what's right and what's wrong right know.

List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
                    wordList.add(word);

And I've added this to store the words, is this the right way to do it?

Comment: k is the index to iterate in the letters of a word...so if (alphabetList[i] == word.charAt(k))

Comment: Ah yes finally! I've put the print statements in the right position and changed the if statement to yours. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: It s not easy try to understand logic of others...so I suggest you to think carefully about the algorithm you are about to implement (without thinking about the code) and next ask for help if you need while implementing it. Btw if you change the type of wordList from List to Set you can avoid repeating words

Comment: Yeah you're right. I've changed it and now it works fine. Thank you for the final help.